# WooCommerce product created by API-REST not showing Publish option

Tags: json, wordpress, woocommerce, product, wordpress-rest-api

We created some products on WooCommerce via REST API using JSON requests.
The products are created correctly on WC however the Publish option is missing. The product stays stuck on Pendeing status and does not allow to Publish.
We want to create them in pending status so the user can later check it up and finnaly publish it manually when the imagens are added.
Do you have any idea about this?

JSON Example:

```
{
    "id": 6621,
    "name": "Test Product 10",
    "slug": "",
    "permalink": "https://test.com/staging/?post_type=product&p=6621",
    "date_created": "2023-04-20T11:49:10",
    "date_created_gmt": "2023-04-20T11:49:10",
    "date_modified": "2023-04-20T10:51:13",
    "date_modified_gmt": "2023-04-20T10:51:13",
    "type": "variable",
    "status": "pending",
    "featured": false,
    "catalog_visibility": "visible",
    "description": "",
    "short_description": "<p>Test Product 10</p>\n",
    "sku": "TIMB01",
    "price": "46.9",
    "regular_price": "",
    "sale_price": "",
    "date_on_sale_from": null,
.....
```

Thank you

We tried to change the status to draft but the it is the same behaviour. No Publish option is visible.
Adding the product manually trhroug Woocommerce permit to showing the publish option imediatly.